# Need help with Plant identification

Tags: identification

What plant is this?

This plant grows as bush, 3-4ft in height and width. It has long pointy leaves and white/yellow flowers. It Blooms mostly during summer months. Located in northern California zone 9b

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Any chance to see picture of opened flower?

Comment: They have a few buds, i will add a picture afterl it blooms

Comment: looks vaguely like flag iris, but flowers will provide a much better clue and/or eliminate many possibilities.

Comment: Can you also add your location please? Hopefully it will bloom soon so a definitive identification can be made.

Comment: FYI, this plant like its other cousins; daylily, calla lily, all irises, are very poisonous to cats.  Unfortunately these plants ATTRACT cats to be eaten.  If you have a cat, just keep an eye out.  If your cat is an outdoor cat then it is vulnerable to your neighbor's lilies and irises and dogs and cars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a white/yellow Iris spuria - seeing an open flower would confirm, but the leaves, buds and seedpods fit with that plant. Iris spuria flowers  a little later than Siberian Iris - link to image here, its the third image on the page http://www.junglekey.com/search.php?query=Iris+spuria&type=image&lang=en&region=us&img=1&adv=1

Sometimes commonly known as Butterfly Iris.

Comment: What a great site, Bamboo! It's a new one for me. Looking closer at the photo (more so the second one), it looks like the seed heads that form on Siberian irises so I agree that it's likely I. spuria.

Comment: @Jude - new to me too, I had googled 'Iris with white flowers', got Iris spuria (eventually) and then googled that to get a good image....

Comment: You search plants in a family like I do! I've been looking over junglekey.com - quite interesting. That's how I 'surf the net' looking over unfamiliar flora and fauna and reading about them. The natural world is endlessly fascinating, whether it's animate or inanimate.